# VS 2013 Release Management: WebDeploy tool parses parameters wrong

Tags: build, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy, release-management

I use VS 2013 Release Management for our WebSite deployment. I have created tool for irmsdeploy.exe and used it in my component as described in this article: http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/2013/11/webdeploy-and-release-management.html

But I have a problem to passing additional parameters to deploy.cmd. __WebAppName__.deploy.cmd /Y "-skip:Directory=DirName" gives me an error:

Unrecognized argument 'DirName'. All arguments must begin with "-".

Error occurs because tool parses last parameter wrong:

-------------------------------------------------------

Start executing msdeploy.exe

-------------------------------------------------------

"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='C:\Path_to_package\Package.zip' -dest:auto,includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"C:\Path_to_package\Package.SetParameters.xml"  -skip:Directory DirName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line should be the following: __WebAppName__.deploy.cmd /Y """-skip:Directory=DirName"""

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the double quotes from "-skip:Directory=DirName".
it seems it takes the string as is and looking for the - before it.

Comment: Can you pleases send the new error? is it diffrent?